# Delete mysql Table row by clicking submit button php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a cart page from a table named `booking` . 
The cart page has `item name` and a`submit` button named "delete".
There has a lot of items in the cart sheet and every item has a "delete" submit type button. 
The items are inside one `form`. 

I need to delete one item from the table `booking` by clicking the "delete" button of the item. 
How can I do it using `PHP`.

```
    <form action="delete.php" method="POST">
       <div>
           <h2>Item1</h2>
           <input type="submit" name="item1" value="delete">
       </div>
       <div>
           <h2>Item2</h2>
           <input type="submit" name="item2" value="delete">
       </div>
       <div>
           <h2>Item3</h2>
           <input type="submit" name="item3" value="delete">
       </div>
       ...
       <!--There has a lot of items like that-->
    </form>
```

Now for example I need to delete `item100`. How can I do it?

Edit: Here is the delete.php code-

```
<?php      
$query = mysql_query("delete from notification where item = 'item100'") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: you should also show us your PHP code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need form and submit input. You could use links:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=100">delete</a>
```

This is a GET so you need to perform a redirect to your incoming page to avoid back button problems or use Ajax or both.

If you want to use your form and submit button you could add some Javascript to set an hidden input or use a <button />

Comment: NEVER delete data with just a link. Sure, it will work, but you might also have a web crawler delete every record in your database!

Answer (score 0):

Although there is sql injection risks you will need to deal with, this is how you would do it using your current method. Keep in mind you will still need to modify your code to prevent sql injections.

```
    <?php $query = mysql_query("delete from notification where item = '".$_POST['name']."'") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```